# Coreldraw not importing symbols properly [SVG]

Tags: svg, unicode, utf-8, fonts, coreldraw

I have a problem with symbols from various fonts not rendering in CorelDraw. 
I am exporting a SVG-file with a specific font-family (UTF-8) such as; Comic Sans MS, Arial etc from a web-based tool that I'm currently developing.

I want the user to be able to insert special characters for that specific font, then be able to open it in CorelDraw rendering these characters properly.

However... this is not the case. Only some fonts work, I'll give you an example below;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE0hF.png (Couldn't embedd image because of reputation)

This is how it renders in CorelDraw with font-family Arial & Comic Sans MS.

The rendering works fine when displayed in a browser though.

Any ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, disregard my previous answer :-)

I'm pretty sure the problem is that Comic Sans doesn't include the characters you're trying to use.

Specifically, the ♠︎ character is assigned to the code point `\u2660`, which is in the *Miscellaneous Symbols* area `\u2600 - \u26FF`. If you check the character maps for Arial and Comic Sans, you'll find that this character exists in [Arial](http://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/arial-unicode/ms-regular) but not in [Comic Sans](http://www.fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/comic-sans/family).

Apparently your browser is choosing alternative glyphs from other fonts, but CorelDraw is not. If your SVG file includes a default font like `sans-serif`, then it should render OK in any browser. If that doesn't help with the appearance of these characters in CorelDraw, then you'll just have to select them individually and change them to a font that does contain the characters.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I don't understand the first part of your answer though. Would the _font_ count itself as modified when I open it in another program? Or would that happen when I try to export the file created with the font per se?

Edit number two:

It works in for example Inkscape, just as it is suppose to.

Comment: @debben Perhaps I misunderstood your question. Are you attempting to add extra characters to existing fonts, or are you just remarking that not all fonts contain these characters that you are trying to use? I just checked my copy of Arial, and I can confirm that it already includes the ♠︎ character. Maybe all you need to do is just add a default value (like `sans-serif`) to your `font-family` attributes.

Comment: I am not trying to add extra characters. I am just trying to make CorelDraw display symbols (that actually do exist in the font itself). The examples I gave, Arial & Comic Sans MS are suppose to both have these symbols in their fonts. When I open up my file that has Arial as font-family and symbols in its text, CorelDraw draws it up fine. When I do the same with Comic Sans MS the figures in the picture are displayed. If I change the font to Arial they display fine. If I use CorelDraws own "symbol drawing tool" I can draw up the Comic Sans MS symbols just fine.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the late response, didn't realize you edited your answer. This is indeed a workaround, that works, too bad it didn't work like I intended it to. The browser will read it just fine (all browsers) yet CorelDraw is the only program that's been bugging me.

This solution will have to do for now. :)

Regards